# Error RecyclerView dentro de otro RecyclerView

Tags: android

Hola Tengo un RecyclerView que esta dentro de otro RecyclerView y en la linea :

```
iconoscantidadgrid.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
```

me sale un error.

¿Porque puede ser?
Este es el primer RecyclerView y el segundo no lo pongo porque no llega a ejecutarse por el error de esta linea.

```
public class RecursosAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<TablaAulas, RecursosAdapter.ViewHolderrecursos> {

private OnRecursosClickListener onRecursosClickListener;
Activity activity;
private Context context;

GridAdapter gridAdapter;
FirebaseFirestore mfirestorerecursos;
RecyclerView iconoscantidadgrid;

// Interface para crear los botones del RecyclerView
public interface OnRecursosClickListener {
    void onImagenEliminarClick(TablaAulas tablaAulas,String idaula);
    void onRecursosClickListener(TablaAulas tablaAulas, String idaula);
}

public void setOnRecursosClickListener(RecursosAdapter.OnRecursosClickListener onRecursosClickListener) {
    this.onRecursosClickListener = onRecursosClickListener;
}

// Constructor
public RecursosAdapter(Context context, @NonNull FirestoreRecyclerOptions<TablaAulas> options, Activity activity) {
    super( options );
    this.context = context;
    this.activity = activity;
  /*  iconoscantidadgrid = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.iconoscantidad_grid);
    iconoscantidadgrid.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
    mfirestorerecursos = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();*/
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecursosAdapter.ViewHolderrecursos onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recursos_list_item, parent, false);
    return new RecursosAdapter.ViewHolderrecursos(view);
}

// Metodo que enlace los datos del ViewHolder con los datos que estamos pasando en los TextView, ......

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolderrecursos holder, int position, @NonNull final TablaAulas tablaAulas) {

    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot = getSnapshots().getSnapshot(holder.getAdapterPosition());
    final String idaula = documentSnapshot.getId();

    iconoscantidadgrid = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.iconoscantidad_grid);
    iconoscantidadgrid.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));
    mfirestorerecursos = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

    holder.nombreaula.setText(tablaAulas.getNombreaula());
    holder.nombrecurso.setText(tablaAulas.getNombrecurso());


    Query queryiconocantidad = mfirestorerecursos.collection( "Recursos" ).whereEqualTo("idaula", tablaAulas.getIdaula());
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<TablaRecursos> tablaIconoCantidadFirestoreRecyclerOptionss = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<TablaRecursos>()
            .setQuery( queryiconocantidad, TablaRecursos.class ).build();
    gridAdapter = new GridAdapter( activity, tablaIconoCantidadFirestoreRecyclerOptionss, activity );
    gridAdapter.startListening();
    gridAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    holder.iconoscantidadgrid.setAdapter( gridAdapter );



    holder.layoutrecurso.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {
              onRecursosClickListener.onRecursosClickListener(tablaAulas, idaula);
          }
    });

    holder.recursoeli.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onRecursosClickListener.onImagenEliminarClick(tablaAulas, idaula);
        }
    });


}

class ViewHolderrecursos extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ImageView recursoeli;
    public TextView nombreaula, nombrecurso;
    public LinearLayout layoutrecurso;
    public RecyclerView iconoscantidadgrid;


    public ViewHolderrecursos(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        recursoeli = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.recurso_eli_list_item);
        nombreaula = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombreaula_list_item);
        nombrecurso = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nombrecurso_list_item);
        layoutrecurso = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.layout_recurso_list_item);
        iconoscantidadgrid = (RecyclerView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iconoscantidad_grid);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: El error creo que es del contexto pero ya he probado muchas cosas y siempre el mismo error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.delgadovalhondo.iesadministrador.Recursos.RecursosAdapter.onBindViewHolder(RecursosAdapter.java:87)

Comment: La línea de código: `iconoscantidadgrid = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.iconoscantidad_grid);` es la que genera el error en sí. El NPE te sale porque el `Activity` no encuentra un `RecyclerView` con el id `R.id.iconoscantidad_grid`, por ende `iconoscantidadgrid` es `null`. Reemplaza `iconoscantidadgrid = (RecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.iconoscantidad_grid);` por 
 `holder.iconoscantidadgrid.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(activity));`

Comment: Muchas gracias, era eso. Asi he empezado un muy buen dia.